# Why doesn't background apply to span tags?

Tags: html, css, background

I am trying to create the four quadrants using CSS.

```css
.top-left {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  border-top-left-radius: 100%;
  width: 100px;
}
.top-right {
  background: green;
  border-top-right-radius: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.bottom-left {
  background: blue;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
.bottom-right {
  background: yellow;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outerCircle">
  <div id="top">
    <span id="red" class="top-left"></span>
    <span id="green" class="top-right"></span>
  </div>
  <div id="bottom">
    <span id="blue" class="bottom-left"></span>
    <span id="yellow" class="bottom-right"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

But nothing is displayed unless I type something in the span tags. How do I display the background without any text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`span`'s are `inline` elements by default, try changing their `display` value to `inline-block`, or `block` as follows:

```css
.top-right, .top-left, .bottom-right, .bottom-left {
  display: inline-block;
}
.top-left{

  background:red;
  height:100px;
  border: solid 2px black;
  border-top-left-radius:100%;
  width:100px;
}



.top-right{
  background:green;
  border: solid 2px black;
  border-top-right-radius:100%;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
}

.bottom-left{
  background:blue;
  border: solid 2px black;
  border-bottom-left-radius:100%;
  height:100px;
width:100px;
}

.bottom-right{
  background:yellow;
  border: solid 2px black;
  border-bottom-right-radius:100%;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outerCircle">
  <div id="top">
    <span id="red" class="top-left"></span>
    <span id="green" class="top-right"></span>
  </div>
  <div id="bottom">
    <span id="blue" class="bottom-left"></span>
    <span id="yellow" class="bottom-right"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

NOTE: I've also tidied up your incorrect CSS markup (you were trying to declare an incorerect property `border-solid:`)

Answer (score 2):

`<span>` is an inline level element, the `width` and `height` doesn't apply by default, you can set it to `display:inline-block` or `display:block` to make it to work.

```css
#outerCircle {
  font-size: 0; /*remove whitespace*/
}

#outerCircle span {
  font-size: 16px; /*reset font-size*/
  display: inline-block;
}

.top-left {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  border-top-left-radius: 100%;
  width: 100px;
}

.top-right {
  background: green;
  border-top-right-radius: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.bottom-left {
  background: blue;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.bottom-right {
  background: yellow;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outerCircle">
  <div id="top">
    <span id="red" class="top-left"></span>
    <span id="green" class="top-right"></span>
  </div>
  <div id="bottom">
    <span id="blue" class="bottom-left"></span>
    <span id="yellow" class="bottom-right"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```